# Windows XP - Windows Update Blocked by company firewall - Can't install driver

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, windows-firewall

My company has blocked Windows update site at the company firewall. However, that also means Windows XP is unable to search on the Microsoft update site for drivers. Therefore, none of the USB devices could be installed and I always ended up with a driver not found error.

Is there anyway I could install the driver otherwise (there is no download available for USB key on the manufacturer's website) such as using Windows XP installation CD (I did a automatic search on the Windows XP installation CD but couldn't find anything as well)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to contact your Windows Domain Administrator.